Next.js Middleware Cookie Deletion and Redirect Not Working Together
I'm working with Next.js 14 and facing an issue in my middleware where I need to delete a cookie based on the user's authentication status and then redirect the user to a specific URL. However, I'm encountering a problem where if I use NextResponse.redirect(loginUrl), the cookie deletion code below it does not execute, leading to the cookie not being deleted as intended.
Below is my middleware implementation:
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { verifyUser } from '@/lib';

export async function middleware(request) {
    const isValidUser = await verifyUser(request);

    const response = NextResponse.next();
    const { pathname, searchParams } = request.nextUrl;
    const previousPageURL = pathname.startsWith('/') ? pathname.slice(1) : null;
    const nextPageURL = searchParams.get('destination') || '/dashboard';
    const isPublicPath = pathname === '/' || pathname === '/login' || pathname === '/signup' || pathname === '/forgotpassword';
    const isPrivatePath = pathname === '/dashboard' || pathname === '/creategroup' || pathname === '/group/:uniqueURL/edit';
    const token = request.cookies.get('auth_token')?.value || '';

    if (token && !isValidUser) {
        response.cookies.delete('auth_token');
    }

    const isAuth = request.cookies.has('auth_token');

    if (isPublicPath && isAuth) {
        response.redirect(new URL(nextPageURL, request.nextUrl));
    }

    if (isPrivatePath && !isAuth) {
        const loginUrl = new URL('/login', request.nextUrl);
        if (previousPageURL) {
            loginUrl.searchParams.set('destination', previousPageURL);
        }
        response.redirect(loginUrl);
    }

    return response;
}

However, I'm getting an error message:
⨯ src\middleware.js (32:17) @ redirect
 ⨯ response.redirect is not a function

I'm trying to achieve the cookie deletion and redirection in a single flow without prematurely returning from the middleware. How can I correctly delete the cookie and perform a redirect within the same middleware execution?
